# how solve the Failed to compile react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
Failed to compile.

./src/logo.svg
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Ahmed Sabry Tamam\g\src\logo.svg'
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show the css?

Comment: is default no thing inside